# jQuery get callback value as variable

Tags: jquery, callback

I want to get callback function value as variable.
I already try it but not working.

```
var Session = '';
    chrome.storage.sync.get('Session', function(data){
        Session = data.Session;
});
alert(Session);
```

I must want to get this session as variable not any other function to execute it.

Comment: `Session = '';
    chrome.storage.sync.get('Session', function(data){
        Session = data.Session;
});
alert(Session);` try this

Comment: `chrome.storage.sync` is **asynchronous**. You can't eat a pizza before it gets delivered